# When can I swap around the order of operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, momentum, hilbert-space

I was doing this question:

> Using $\left< x \middle| p\right> = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}}e^{ipx/\hbar}$ show that:
>
> $$ \left<x \middle| \hat{p} \middle| \psi \right> = -i\hbar \frac{d}{dx} \left< x \middle| \psi\right> $$
>   for a general $\psi$.

---

### **Method 1** (how my lecturer did it)

\begin{align*}
\left<x \middle| \hat{p} \middle| \psi \right> &= \int dp \, \left<x \middle| p\right> \left<p \middle| \hat{p} \middle| \psi \right> \\
&= \int dp \, p \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}}e^{ipx/\hbar} \left<p \middle|\psi\right> \\
&= \int dp \, (-i\hbar) \frac{d}{dx}\left<x \middle| p\right>\left<p\middle|\psi\right> \\
&= -i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}\left<x \middle|\psi\right>
\end{align*}

Here I want to ask:

1. **Why do put it in integral form? (See below why I think it's unnessessary)**
2. **Why are we allowed to swap the operator order like we did in line 3?**

---

### **Method 2** (how I did it seeing that we can just swap the order)

\begin{align*}
\left<x \middle| \hat{p} \middle| \psi \right> &= \left<x \middle| p\right> \left<p \middle| \hat{p} \middle| \psi \right> \\
&= \hat{p} \left<x \middle|p\right>\left<p\middle|\psi\right> \\
&= \hat{p} \left<x \middle| \psi\right> \\
&= - i \hbar \frac{d}{dx} \left< x\middle| \psi\right>
\end{align*}

I don't understand why putting it in integral form is even correct?

Comment: Method 2 is an incorrect version of Method 1...

Comment: Can you expand? How so?

Comment: Method 1 is incorrect anyway. On the third line, the $\hat{p}$ should just be $p$, i.e. the *eigenvalue* of the operator $\hat{p}$ corresponding to the eigenvector $\lvert p\rangle$. However Method 2 is doubly incorrect, since you need to integrate over all $p$ to use the resolution of identity $1 = \int\mathrm{d}p\,\lvert p \rangle\langle p \rvert$.

Comment: You're right, that was just me mistyping it. I'll edit it.

Comment: @PPG So do you understand now why there is no "swapping of operator order"? $p$ is not an operator.

Comment: Sort of. I don't understand where the eigenvalue comes from.

Comment: @PPG The very definition of the state $\lvert p \rangle$ is that it is an eigenstate of the momentum operator $\hat p$, that is, it fulfils the equation $\hat p \lvert p \rangle = p \lvert p \rangle$, where $p$ is the eigenvalue.

Comment: @PPG Already fixed the typo, my edit will just have to get through the review.

Comment: In "method 2": the first equality is wrong, the second is kind of right if you replace the operator by the number (eigenvalue), the third is wrong again, the fourth is wrong and it is just you forcing in the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your lecturer got the eigenvalue using the fact that the operator $\hat{p}$ is Hermitian so you can do this:

\begin{align}
    \langle p| \hat{p} &= \left( \hat{p}^\dagger |p\rangle\right)^\dagger\\
     &= \left( \hat{p} |p\rangle\right)^\dagger\\
     &= \left( p |p\rangle\right)^\dagger\\
     &= \langle p| p
\end{align}

I think it becomes a bit neater if you put the projector $|p\rangle\langle p|$ after the operator $\hat{p}$ because then you don't have to do the gymnastics with the Hermitian conjugate. This would be my attempt (being as explicit as possible at each step):

\begin{align}
\langle x|\hat{p} |\psi\rangle &= \int dp \langle x|\hat{p} |p\rangle\langle p|\psi\rangle\\
&= \int dp p \langle x |p\rangle\langle p|\psi\rangle\\
&= \int dp p e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}xp}\langle p|\psi\rangle\\
&= \int dp \left(-i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}\right) e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}xp}\langle p|\psi\rangle\\
&= \left(-i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}\right)\int dp  e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}xp}\langle p|\psi\rangle\\
&= \left(-i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}\right)\int dp  \langle x|p\rangle\langle p|\psi\rangle\\
&= \left(-i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}\right)\langle x|\psi\rangle\\
\end{align}

Note that it is the number $p$ that is brought to the front in line two *not* the operator $\hat{p}$. We choose the states $|p\rangle$ so that we have the following equality: $\hat{p}|p\rangle = p|p\rangle$.